# TSNE in sklearn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a small problem using [t-SNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html#sklearn.manifold.TSNE) in python.

I take a small dataset :

```
A = np.matrix([[0.2,  0.3, 0.6, 0.8], 
               [0.2,  0.25, 0.55, 0.85],
               [0.2,  0.3, 0.6, 0.8],
               [0.64,  0.8, 0.2, 0.2],
               [0.65,  0.8, 0.2, 0.2],
               [0.65,  0.75, 0.2, 0.15], 
               [0.7,  0.8, 0.2, 0.2]])
```

Then, I run the t-SNE on it, with this command :

```
tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2,random_state=0, metric=Distance)
```

Here, `Distance` is a function which takes two array as input, calculates the distance between them and return the distance. 
This function works. I could see the output changing if I change my values.

```
def Distance(X,Y):
   Result = spatial.distance.euclidean(X,Y)
   return Result
```

But the visualisation doesn't change using the t-sne ... and the visualisation doesn't respect the distance between my points.

And if I remove the metric :

```
tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2,random_state=0)
```

It still give me the same result ...

[image]

Do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the default `metric` is `euclidean`. So actually you are not changing anything compared to the default setting. You can see the default parameters at [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html).
Also I have copy and pasted them here:

```
class sklearn.manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=30.0, early_exaggeration=4.0, learning_rate=1000.0, n_iter=1000, n_iter_without_progress=30, min_grad_norm=1e-07, metric='euclidean', init='random', verbose=0, random_state=None, method='barnes_hut', angle=0.5)
```